# Position relative element same distance from top as left

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Is it possible to have a relative element replicate the margin on the left of the div and use it as a margin on the top? Basically I have an element that should be equal distance from the top and left hand side of the browser.

Currently I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { 
    min-height: 2000px;
}

#container { 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14.25%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 8.875%;
    left: 5.25%;
    position: fixed;
    background: lightyellow;
}

#content {
    width: 71.75%;
    position: relative;
    left: 14.25%;
    background: lightpink;
}
```

As you can see I have specified the margin for `#content` to be 14.25% and I'd like this to be same distance to be used for the top margin, but alas specifiying 14.25% again does not work.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pa8qsd55/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't defined a **margin** on `#content` you've defined a position. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Let me introduce you to `vw` and `vh`!
When you want a certain percent (like 15%) from top, on a fixed element, it means if we divide the viewport height to 100 parts, 15 parts from top is the value we are looking for.
so if you set your `#container`'s top to 15vh and `#sidebar` left also to 15vh, it will always will have the same distance from top and left.
here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa8qsd55/2/).

```
#container { 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15vh;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 8.875%;
    left: 15vh;
    position: fixed;
    background: lightyellow;
}
```

Note: watch out for [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)!

Comment: if you want a solution for older browsers note that margin and padding are always calculated from the width if given in percent, so a margin-top of 10% is 10% of the WIDTH not the HEIGHT, you could then so something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pa8qsd55/3/

Answer (score 0):

If browser support for the solution provided by @Ramtin is a concern for you, and if you are open to use script; you may try setting the desired attributes using jQuery as below:

```
var left = $('#content').css('left');
$('#container').css('top',left);
```